# Visual Studio 2013 Javascript Apache Cordova Project: How To

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I just wonder how to do some events with Javascript Apache Cordova project on Visual Studio

- Do i need to create new js file for each html file (like Controller - View on MVC)
- What is the events fire sort ? (Which event first, which event next firing )
- I do same sample, i put one button and when i click button i open new page, when i fire backbutton, first page comes, but button on the first page not working anymore, what is wrong ?
- And at last, how can store some data on SQLite database localy and do some read,write,list actions ? Is there any sample code with these ?

Thanks everybody,

Answer (score 1):

1. *Do i need to create new js file for each html file (like Controller - View on MVC)*.

It's not necessary, you can put all code to one .js file. Depends on your coding style and used framework.

2. *What is the events fire sort ? (Which event first, which event next firing )*.

Cordova app, in fact, is a web page in mobile browser. So you should read proper docs. For special Cordova events see this page: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events

3. *I do same sample, i put one button .....*

First af all, it's recommended to use Single-Page-Application, for details see there: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_next_index.md.html#Best%20Practices. As for your app, you shoukd provide some more details. Looks, like you missed some script or link while reloading first page.

4. *how can store some data on SQLite database localy*

First, read this page about storage: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage. It's recommended to use WebSQL, but you can try this plugin: https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin, or read this article about WebSQL: http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/05/05/websql-plugin-for-apache-cordova/